# VBA code for todays date and time in a specified format

Tags: excel, vba

How am I able to get todays date and time in this specific format?
Date / Time: 24.10.2019 / 08:45:57

Comment: Where do you want the Date formated, in VBA, an query or in a report/form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Because you've tagged the question with VBA, try this code:

```
Debug.Print Format(Now,"dd.mm.yyyy / hh:nn:ss")
```

The output of this will be:

```
09.03.2020 / 12:29:40
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to include the "`Date / Time:`" element, you'll need to use the escape characters to allow the `D` and `m` to present correctly.

```
Debug.Print Format(now,"\Date / Ti\me: dd.mm.yyyy / hh:nn:ss")
```

If you're looking to do this in a sheet, you need to escape other characters;

```
=TEXT(now(),"\Dat\e \/ Ti\m\e : dd.mm.yyyy / hh:mm:ss")
```

Obviously, alternatives would include prefixing the formatting with text e.g.

```
Debug.Print "Date / Time: " & Format(now,"dd.mm.yyyy / hh:nn:ss")
or
="Date/Time : " & TEXT(NOW(),"dd.mm.yyyy / hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Yes, the last one worked perfectly well. Thank you so much.